# Selection of the hierarchical list was not performed in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Hierarchical data was used with a list, but selection was not performed. I was unable to identify my mistake. I have added my code below for reference.
Thanks in Advance

```
struct Node: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var childNodes: [Node]?
}

struct HierarchicalData_List: View {
    @State var dataSource = [
        Node(name: "1", childNodes: [Node(name: "1.1")]),
        Node(name: "2", childNodes: [Node(name: "2.1", childNodes: [Node(name: "2.1.1")])])]
    @State var selectedNode: Set<Node> = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(dataSource, children: \.childNodes, selection: $selectedNode) { node in
                Text(node.name)
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `Text(node.name).tag(node)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I thought that would work too, but it doesn't for some reason. You can't select the child nodes.

Comment: works for me. I'll post my test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection binding should be a `Set` of values that is the same type as the `ID` type of the data.

Here, `Node.id` is of type `String`, so the `selectedNode` should be a `Set<String>`.

```
@State var selectedNode: Set<String> = []
```

If this is undesirable, you should make `Node.id` of type `Node`. That is, each `Node` uses itself as its ID.

```
struct Node: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let uuid: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var childNodes: [Node]?
    
    var id: Node { self }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass the identity key path `\.self` to the `id:` parameter of `List.init`.

```
List(dataSource, id: \.self, children: \.childNodes, selection: $selectedNode) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that works for me on MacOS 14.2 using Xcode 15.1.

```
struct Node: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var childNodes: [Node]?
}

struct HierarchicalData_List: View {
    @State var dataSource = [
        Node(name: "1", childNodes: [Node(name: "1.1")]),
        Node(name: "2", childNodes: [Node(name: "2.1", childNodes: [Node(name: "2.1.1")])])]
    @State var selectedNode: Set<Node> = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(dataSource, children: \.childNodes, selection: $selectedNode) { node in
                Text(node.name).tag(node) // <--- here
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
            Spacer()
            Text("selections")
            // --- here for testing show the selections in red
            List(Array(selectedNode)) { node in
                Text(node.name).foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HierarchicalData_List()
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work too, but I can't select 2.1.1 and 1.1 with this. That said, I'm still using Xcode 15.0 and Ventura, so maybe that's why...

Comment: the older system is most likely the culprit in your case. On MacOS Sonoma 14.2, I can select, child, parents whatever, and it works.